# Auto sorter in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My program works but it takes almost a minute to update/sort an entry. How do I make it instant or at least only a couple of seconds? I have one function sort and another function that activates the sort on edit

```
function autoSort(e){
    const row = e.range.getRow()
    const column = e.range.getColumn()
    
    if(!(column === 1 && row >=4)) return

    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Week 3")
    const range = ws.getRange(4,1,ws.getLastRow() -1,5)

    range.sort({column: 1, ascending: false})

} 


function onEdit(e){

  autoSort(e)

}
```

Comment: About `My program works but it takes almost a minute to update/sort an entry.`, in your Spreadsheet, how many data rows are there in the sheet?

Comment: There are 1000 rows in the sheet but only about 30 of them have actual data in it

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `There are 1000 rows in the sheet but only about 30 of them have actual data in it` and your showing script, I thought that the processing time of the script might not be so long. So, in order to correctly replicate `My program works but it takes almost a minute to update/sort an entry.`, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Basically, I type in the team name the score, and then the date, and it's supposed to sort it by date, with the furthest away date at the top. But since I last responded, without changing the code at all it no longer works, no matter how long I wait.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.